# Open an activity from a Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, buttonclick

Whenever I use or implement `onClickListner` in `Fragment`, the application crashes. I have tried all the methods like implementing the fragment class using on click in XML but the application crashes all the time. Please help me with this. I don’t even write anything in the `onClick` override method and still, the application crashes.

```
Button btn_edit;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.multi_frag,container,false);
     btn_edit=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
     btn_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {

         }
     });
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_account,container,false);
 }
```

Comment: add your logcat of error

Comment: Thankyou so much but i found the correct way.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application is crashing because you are returning a different view and finding the button in a different view.

```
// In below line you are using R.layout.multi_frag 

View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.multi_frag,container,false);
btn_edit=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
btn_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
});
// And here, you are returning R.layout.activity_account.

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_account,container,false);
```

You cannot use two layouts within one fragment. Check the right layout which contains the button and use that layout in both of the places.